# Maven 3.2.1 + Hibernate 4.3.4 - Unable to build entity manager factory - Caused by: ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven-2, log4j

I have migrated a Hibernate 4.3.4 to a Maven 3.2.1 project. I have created just one jar file with maven-shade-plugin, but when I start it I have the following exception:

```
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:35 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider               [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use     [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:35 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:35 AM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider     [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use     [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:35 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper     logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: MfsDao
    ...]
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:36 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:36 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties:     {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false,     hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:36 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 17, 2014 10:44:44 AM     org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at de.cegelec.vwezlt.mfs.dao.MfsEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory(MfsEntityManager.java:117)
at de.cegelec.vwezlt.mfs.dao.MfsEntityManager.getMfsEntityManager(MfsEntityManager.java:25)
at de.cegelec.vwezlt.mfsvert.main.MfsVert.main(MfsVert.java:168)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:67)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2690)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2641)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1129)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:846)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
```

I have debugged and I have found that the class which raises the exception is `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jpa.converter.ContextMapAttributeConverter`.

In my pom I have a dependency with log4j 2.0-rc1 as dependency:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-rc1</version>
  </dependency>
```

It has worked fine before I tried to integrate all in Maven.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by aaronfc already, there is an open ticket on hibernate JIRA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8804

So the Problem is an collision with Log4j2 converters, more detailed, the db appender JPA converters.

However, the problems occurs with the "fat" jar only...

**Workaround:** If you use *maven-shade-plugin* to pack your jar - and don't need any log4j2 db appender, you could exclude the colliding Converter classes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName> 
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/db/jpa/converter/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This works for me, as in - delete the converter package directly from the jar. @hartmut, do you have any idea how to automate this in Gradle?

Comment: OK, answered my own question, see my extended answer below

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this also. There is an open ticket on https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8804

I "workarounded" it by downgrading to Hibernate 4.2.12.Final and JPA2.0. Hope it helps!

Edit:
Sorry, didn't see that this was a two months old post, anyway hope it is useful for somebody :P

Answer (score 1):

In extension to @hartmut's answer, if you're using Gradle, include [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), and do the following in build.gradle:

```
shadowJar {
    exclude 'org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/db/jpa/converter/*'
}
```

You can then run gradle shadowJar to create the jar

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that works. Instead to create a "fat" jar, I have created a Jar with my project and all the dependencies in a separate "lib" folder (included Hibernate of course).

I don't know way, but it works now.